# Unable to install VNC applications on my UBUNTU VM

Tags: software-installation, vnc

I am trying to install VNC applications on the Client's VM which is a Ubuntu system. But when I run the command "sudo apt update", I am getting this error *Could not connect to 10.210.40.36:3128 (10.210.40.36), connection timed out*
I am not sure what is this IP and what to do to resolve this issue.

```
db2inst1@product-env:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for db2inst1: 
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                               
  Could not connect to 10.210.40.36:3128 (10.210.40.36), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                       
  Unable to connect to 10.210.40.36:3128:
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                     
  Unable to connect to 10.210.40.36:3128:
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                 
  Could not connect to 10.210.40.36:3128 (10.210.40.36), connection timed out
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                     
  Could not connect to 10.210.40.36:3128 (10.210.40.36), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
9 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to 10.210.40.36:3128 (10.210.40.36), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 10.210.40.36:312
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: It seems that you have some local proxy configured. archive.ubuntu.com is not at that IP

Comment: You have some sort of proxy at play in your environment that you cannot connect to.  It's likely configured in your APT settings somewhere.  You will need to disable the proxy and deconfigure it in order to reach out to the Internet.  If you are unsure how this IP got in your system, then this is something that your client may have set up and installed or is part of their environment, and you need to work with them to figure out what to do about it.

Comment: Hi Thomas Ward, Is there any way that I can connect with you and discuss about my issue

Comment: Hi Thomas Ward, Please let me know where can I disable the proxy.

Comment: Run the following and include the output as an edit to your question:  `cd /etc/apt/ && grep -ir 'proxy'`